# Script to type command into specific terminal window before automatic shutdown or shutdown Mac

Tags: macos, server

So basically what I am doing is running a Minecraft server in my terminal window on an old 2009 iMac running MacOS Sierra and I have everything all setup to run the server.
At 1:00AM the computer shuts down to rest.
At 4:00AM the computer starts up, logs in, and reboots the Minecraft server.

However, the thing is with Minecraft servers. You need to type "stop" to have the server properly shutdown. And I don't think its healthy for my server to be doing force shutdowns everyday.

So what I need is some ideas on how to write a script to type "stop"
into the terminal window just before shutdown.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Launchd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) is the OS X tool of choice for this sort of thing. You can also take a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542301/running-a-shell-script-on-shutdown-via-launchd). In essence, you need to setup the script that shuts down Minecraft during the server shutdown.